# how to get forgot password with grails application using spring security core plugin?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, email-confirmation

In my grails application,i am using spring security core plugin for security,and email confirmation plugin for email validity,now i need to implement code for forget password.

Do i need to use spring security ui plugin or i can achiebe it with existing plugins?

With thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Since passwords are stored with one-way encryption, there's no way to retrieve the original cleartext password (unless you store it unencrypted, which is a bad idea). So the workflow in the UI plugin involves resetting the password via email.

You can install that, but you don't have to use the UI plugin - feel free to copy the implementation and use it in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a [reset password feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654770/grails-acegi-plugin-lost-password/2172671#2172671) using the email confirmation plugin. This was when I was using the Acegi security plugin (the Spring Security plugin's ancestor), but AFAIK it should work with the Spring Security plugin too.